# python sum on array of tensors vs tf.add_n

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I've got some code

```
tensors = [] //its filled with 3D float tensors
total = sum(tensors)
```

if I change that last line to

```
total = tf.add_n(tensors)
```

then the code produces the same output but runs much more slowly and soon causes
an out-of-memory exception. Whats going on here? Can someone explain how pythons built in sum function and tf.add_n interact with an array of tensors respectively and why pythons sum would seemingly just be a better version?

Answer (score 6):

When you use `sum`, you call a standard python algorithm that call `__add__` recursively on the elements of the array. Since `__add__` (or `+`) indeed is overloaded on tensorflow's tensors, it works as expected: it creates a graph that can be executed during a session. It is not optimal, however, because you add as many operation as there are elements in your list; also, you are enforcing the order of the operation (add the first two elements, then the third to the result, and so on), which is also not optimal.

By contrast, `add_n` is a specialized operation to do just that. Looking at the graph is really telling I think:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope('sum'):
  xs = [tf.zeros(()) for _ in range(10)]
  sum(xs)

with tf.variable_scope('add_n'):
  xs = [tf.zeros(()) for _ in range(10)]
  tf.add_n(xs)
```

[image]

However – contrary to what I thought earlier – `add_n` takes up more memory because it waits – and store – for all incoming inputs before storing them. If the number of inputs is large, then the difference can be substantial.

The behavior I was expecting from `add_n`, that is, summation of inputs as they are available, is actually achieved by [`tf.accumulate_n`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/accumulate_n). This should be the superior alternative, as it takes less memory than `add_n` but does not enforce the order of summation like `sum`.

Why did the authors of tensorflow-wavenet used `sum` instead of `tf.accumulate_n`? Certainly because before this function is not differentiable on TF < 1.7. So if you have to support TF < 1.7 *and* be memory efficient, good old `sum` is actually quite a good option.

Comment: Well its not my code. If you're really interested here is the repo. https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet Simply changing the line in model.py _create_network function causes it to reach OOM exception very quickly on my GPU

Answer (score 1):

The [sum() built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) only takes iterables and therefor would seem to gain the advantage of using generators in regards to memory profile.

the [add_n() function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_n) for tensor takes a list of tensors and seem to retain that data structure throughout handling based on it's requirement for shape comparison.

```
In [29]: y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]  

In [30]: y.__sizeof__()
Out[30]: 120

In [31]: x = iter(y)

In [32]: x.__sizeof__()
Out[32]: 32
```